# voice over button "information" pin map

Tags: ios, dictionary

how do i pronounce as voice over, when you click the button ( the circle with a letter "i") that appears when you select a pin map ? now, voice over, says " button " but I would like him to say " information "

import UIKit
import MapKit
import AddressBookUI

class MapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, MapManagerDelegate {

```
// MARK: - Outlet
@IBOutlet var myMap: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!



// MARK: - Metodi standard del controller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // NSLocalizedString legge la chiave dai file Localizable.strings
    // fa tutto in automatico in base alla lingua di iOS
    // se la lingua non c'è (esmepio iOS è in francese, ma il francese non 'cè) l'App usa Base
    // quindi la traduzione che metti nell'Inglese che deve essere uguale a quella di Base
    // l'Inglese deve essere la lingua base che carica quando non trova una certa lingua
    title = NSLocalizedString("APPTITLE", comment: "")

    myMap.delegate = self
    myMap.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.Follow

    MapManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    MapManager.sharedInstance.controller = self
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    MapManager.sharedInstance.startUpdateLocation()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

// MARK: - Delegati

//MapManagerDelegate

func incomingUserLocation(region: MKCoordinateRegion) {
    //println("incomingUserLocation")
    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    MapManager.sharedInstance.currentMap = myMap
    MapManager.sharedInstance.searchPoiWithName("farmacia")

    // I punti di interesse funzionano indipendentemente dalla lingua
    // quindi lascia pharmacy, ovvero farmacia in inglese

}

func incomingPin(pin: Pin) {
    //println("pin!")
    myMap.addAnnotation(pin)
}

func didFinishSearchPoi() {
    //println("didFinishSearchPoi")
    MapManager.sharedInstance.stopUpdateLocation()
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

func incomingError(error: NSError) {
    print("error: \(error)")
    MapManager.sharedInstance.stopUpdateLocation()
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

//MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annView : MKPinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "currentloc")
    annView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 229/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1.0)
    annView.animatesDrop = true
    annView.canShowCallout = true
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-8, 0)

    annView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView

    return annView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    var pin = view.annotation as! Pin


    func apriMappe(action : UIAlertAction!) {

        let endLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: view.annotation!.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let endItem = MKMapItem(placemark: endLocation)
        endItem.name = view.annotation!.title!
        let opzioniLancio = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

        endItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(opzioniLancio)

              }

    func telefona(action : UIAlertAction!) {


        let cutSpace = pin.phone.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s",
                                                           withString: "",
                                                              options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch,
                                                                range: nil)
        let cutInter = (cutSpace as NSString).substringFromIndex(4)
        let phone = "tel://" + cutInter
        print(phone)

        if let url = NSURL(string: phone) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }

    let myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("PRIMAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                        message: nil,
                                 preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("SECONDAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                        handler: telefona))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TERZAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                        handler: apriMappe))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("QUARTAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
                                        handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Azioni

@IBAction func ricarica(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //println("ricarica")
    myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    MapManager.sharedInstance.startUpdateLocation()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

}

[image: console error]

```
import UIKit
```

import MapKit
import AddressBookUI

class MapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, MapManagerDelegate {

```
// MARK: - Outlet
@IBOutlet var myMap: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!



// MARK: - Metodi standard del controller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // NSLocalizedString legge la chiave dai file Localizable.strings
    // fa tutto in automatico in base alla lingua di iOS
    // se la lingua non c'è (esmepio iOS è in francese, ma il francese non 'cè) l'App usa Base
    // quindi la traduzione che metti nell'Inglese che deve essere uguale a quella di Base
    // l'Inglese deve essere la lingua base che carica quando non trova una certa lingua
    title = NSLocalizedString("APPTITLE", comment: "")

    myMap.delegate = self
    myMap.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.Follow

    MapManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    MapManager.sharedInstance.controller = self
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    MapManager.sharedInstance.startUpdateLocation()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func pushAViewController() {

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

// MARK: - Delegati

//MapManagerDelegate

func incomingUserLocation(region: MKCoordinateRegion) {
    //println("incomingUserLocation")
    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    MapManager.sharedInstance.currentMap = myMap
    MapManager.sharedInstance.searchPoiWithName("farmacia")

    // I punti di interesse funzionano indipendentemente dalla lingua
    // quindi lascia pharmacy, ovvero farmacia in inglese

}

func incomingPin(pin: Pin) {
    //println("pin!")
    myMap.addAnnotation(pin)
}

func didFinishSearchPoi() {
    //println("didFinishSearchPoi")
    MapManager.sharedInstance.stopUpdateLocation()
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

func incomingError(error: NSError) {
    print("error: \(error)")
    MapManager.sharedInstance.stopUpdateLocation()
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

//MKMapViewDelegate



func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annView : MKPinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "currentloc")
    annView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 229/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1.0)
    annView.animatesDrop = true
    annView.canShowCallout = true
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-8, 0)

    annView.autoresizesSubviews = true


    let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "pushAViewController:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    button.accessibilityLabel="Informazioni"

    return annView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    var pin = view.annotation as! Pin


    func apriMappe(action : UIAlertAction!) {

        let endLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: view.annotation!.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let endItem = MKMapItem(placemark: endLocation)
        endItem.name = view.annotation!.title!
        let opzioniLancio = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

        endItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(opzioniLancio)

              }

    func telefona(action : UIAlertAction!) {


        let cutSpace = pin.phone.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s",
                                                           withString: "",
                                                              options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch,
                                                                range: nil)
        let cutInter = (cutSpace as NSString).substringFromIndex(4)
        let phone = "tel://" + cutInter
        print(phone)

        if let url = NSURL(string: phone) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }

    let myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("PRIMAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                        message: nil,
                                 preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("SECONDAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                        handler: telefona))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TERZAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                        handler: apriMappe))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("QUARTAVOCEMENU", comment: ""),
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
                                        handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Azioni

@IBAction func ricarica(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //println("ricarica")
    myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)
    MapManager.sharedInstance.findLocation = false
    MapManager.sharedInstance.startUpdateLocation()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

}

Comment: so instead of voice over say button, you want it say information ?

Comment: exactly. now says " button " but I would like him to say " information "

Comment: change the accessibilityTraits from button to simple text.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be more specific please? are just starting out with the development and this thing is the first time that happens to me

Comment: Could you pls show the code that adds button to the annotation pin / or code related to the annotaion pin

Comment: edit my answer...see code... ;)

Comment: r u talking about rightCalloutAccessoryView ?

Comment: but only if you ' user activates voice over . I would say that " information " because currently says " button " when you select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a button directly to the rightCalloutAccessoryView. Declare the button separetley, and give its reference to the rightCalloutAccessoryView.

So your code at this line :

```
 annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView
```

will be changed to:

```
var button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
button.addTarget(self, action: "yourMEthodName:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

And now you can change the button accessibility trait as follows:

```
   button.accessibilityTraits=UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText
```

or

```
    button.accessibilityTraits = .StaticText
```

and change the accessibility LAbel for the button as:

```
    button.accessibilityLabel=@"Information"
```

and the voice over will now read the button as Information when u tap on it.

Note: Declare the button target method as follows :

```
 func pushAViewController(sender:UIButton!)
    { 
    print("Button Clicked")
    }
```

Comment: try to declare it like this :      func pushAViewController(sender:UIButton!)
  {
     print("Button Clicked")
  }

Comment: but when I put the new method that I 've written before , you remove the comment on line button.addTarget ( self , action: " pushAViewController : " forControlEvents : .TouchDown )

Comment: the consul gave me back " button clicked " .. now try with voice over to see if I hear " information "

Comment: I tried voice over and only works that I locate the word " information " . I would not say that in two languages ​​. I located the string but I do not say the word in the language locazzata but tells me the name I used in localizable.string

Comment: in that case, use the localisable string in the accessibility label

Comment: I used

 button.addTarget ( self , action: " pushAViewController : " forControlEvents : .TouchDown )
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
        button.accessibilityLabel = " VOCEGUIDA "


Voice guidance is the name I assigned to the word " information " in different languages ​​, in the files but localizable.string voice over reads me " voceguida " and not " information "

Comment: and what could be? I located in the best way with localizable.string but does not work! voice-over reads the key localizable and not "information"